# Trying to clear multiple JTextfields using a Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I've tried to get this to work but so far I have been unsuccessful. I am hoping that I can clear multiple JTextFields using a button. Below is my code
I'm a beginner. The form won't clear on click.

My form has 5 JTextFields I want to be able to clear them on the click of a button

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AddAnimalForm extends JDialog {
    private JPanel root;
    private JTextField GName;
    private JTextField CommonName;
    private JTextField Price;
    private JTextField Gender;
    private JTextField Colour;
    private JButton addAnimalsButton;
    private JButton clearFormButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
        }

    public AddAnimalForm(Frame owner) {
        super(owner, "Adding Animals", true);
        setContentPane(root);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        addAnimalsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //main.addAnimal();
            }
        });
        clearFormButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Gender.setText("");
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: unclosed `{`(after `private JButton clearFormButton;`? ...plz better indent)

Comment: @xerx593 it is closed on line 40 according to my IDE. Should it be closed earlier?

Comment: what does it? (..actually... remove completely!)

Comment: @xerx593 This causes another 14 errors if i remove it.

Comment: ...bt my question? :) ..and still, plz better indent :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Got to agree with @SergiyMedvynskyy here. The code currently in the question never instantiates any of the text fields or adds them to the GUI. The dialog is never set to visible so running the class achieves nothing useful before the main thread ends. Tips: Remove three of the fields and the redundant button. Instantiate the remaining two fields and add them, and the button, to the dialog before setting it visible. Please ***read*** the link provided for the MCVE. It's important that you can prepare an MCVE of a problem, if expecting to get help on SO.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why did you place your { there? If you want to add the actionlistener to the clearFormButton, you should do it in your constructor (like you did with addAnimalsButton) and remove the starting {.

Comment: Please forgive me i'm a complete Java Beginner. Only started today.

Yes it runs but the text field does not clear? @Keven Renaers

Comment: Is it possible to place your full code here? Because at the moment, we can't see where you place the textfields or buttons,...
And as a suggestion, your variables can best start with a lower case character (see [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.htm))

Comment: What do you mean by full code? This is all my code for this Form

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot you were using a form. And you can fix it by placing the setVisible(true) as the last line of code in your constructor, so after you attach your listeners.

Comment: Yea i tired that earlier. Still not clearing the textfield

Comment: If you try it with the lastest edit, it should work.